# Get file path and name from android locally

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am new to android development, and I am using intent to choose a file locally so I can upload it to some cloud storage. I have been realizing a lot that the file names returned are in the form `image:b` for some number `b`. For example for a file I get `path = /document/image:91` and `filename = image:91`. Does this mean that my result is wrong? I was expecting to get the actual file name. I just want to know if my code is correct.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "requestCode: " + requestCode);
    Log.d(TAG, "resultCode: " + resultCode);
    Log.d(TAG, "Actiity.RESULT_OK: " + Activity.RESULT_OK);
    Log.d(TAG, "intent data: " + data);


    if (requestCode == CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        Uri image = data.getData();
        String path = image.getPath();
        this.file = new File(path);
        String filename = image.getLastPathSegment();
        //File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/CustomFolder/" + filename);
        Log.d(TAG, "file name: " + filename);
        Log.d(TAG, "file path: " + path);
        this.fileName.setText(filename);


    }
}
```

Start Intent.

```
public void onClickSelectPhoto(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE);
}
```

Comment: You can try library: https://github.com/Angads25/android-filepicker, It will return correct  path